# Arranging Rows with Similar Column Data Together After Using ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using `ORDER BY Date DESC` in this table:

```
Number |   Date
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   2   |  07/18/2017
   2   |  07/18/2017
   2   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   2   |  07/19/2017
   3   |  07/19/2017
   3   |  07/19/2017
   3   |  07/19/2017
   4   |  07/19/2017
   4   |  07/19/2017
   3   |  07/19/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   2   |  07/20/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
```

will yield the same result, the problem is how can I re-arrange the rows so that those with similar `Number` will be grouped together in respect to the `Date` using a single query run *(if possible)*?

I tried ordering by `Date` then run another query that orders the `Number`, but the grouped similar `Number` regardless of `Date`

**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```
Number |   Date
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   1   |  07/18/2017
   2   |  07/18/2017
   2   |  07/18/2017
   2   |  07/18/2017
   2   |  07/19/2017
   3   |  07/19/2017
   3   |  07/19/2017
   3   |  07/19/2017
   3   |  07/19/2017
   4   |  07/19/2017
   4   |  07/19/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   1   |  07/20/2017
   2   |  07/20/2017
```

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY Number, Date ORDER BY Date DESC` ? Unless I didn't understood what it is you want to achieve

Comment: @Misery Wouldn't I receive an error for using `GROUP BY` by not using an aggregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `ID` in `Order By` after `date`

```
ORDER BY Date DESC,ID ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected results, both needs to be ASC, What is differece here?

```
Order by [date], Id --which means both asc
```

Output as below:

```
+----+------------+
| Id |    date    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2017-07-18 |
|  1 | 2017-07-18 |
|  1 | 2017-07-18 |
|  1 | 2017-07-18 |
|  1 | 2017-07-18 |
|  1 | 2017-07-18 |
|  2 | 2017-07-18 |
|  2 | 2017-07-18 |
|  2 | 2017-07-18 |
|  2 | 2017-07-19 |
|  3 | 2017-07-19 |
|  3 | 2017-07-19 |
|  3 | 2017-07-19 |
|  3 | 2017-07-19 |
|  4 | 2017-07-19 |
|  4 | 2017-07-19 |
|  1 | 2017-07-20 |
|  1 | 2017-07-20 |
|  1 | 2017-07-20 |
|  1 | 2017-07-20 |
|  1 | 2017-07-20 |
|  2 | 2017-07-20 |
+----+------------+
```

Comment: I didn't really know that I can have multiple column in `ORDER BY`